# How to run J2ME MIDlet programs in JCreator IDE?

Tags: java-me, midp, jcreator

How to run J2ME MIDlet programs in JCreator IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible !!
develop a j2me project then test it with j2me platform
but jcreator by default doesn't support j2me application!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can import the Project in to any one of these IDEs:

1. Eclipse IDE for JAVA ME
2. Java Netbeans IDE